# std::string resize is ruining compare operator (==)

Tags: c++, string, compare

std::string resize causes strings that appear to be equal to no longer be equal. It can appear to be misleading when I hover over the variable in my debugger and they appear to hold the same value.

I think it comes down to the fact that I expected the == operator to stop at the first null character but it keeps going till the end of the size. I'm sure this is working as intended but I was stuck on an issue caused by this for a while so I wanted to see why you would keep comparing characters even after the first null character. thanks!

```c++
int main(void)
{
    std::string test1;
    test1.resize(10);
    test1[0] = 'a';

    std::string test2 = "a";

    //they are not equal
    bool same = (test1 == test2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I expected the == operator to stop at the first null character* -- A `std::string` is not determined by a null terminator.  It is not a C-style string.

Comment: *when I hover over the variable in my debugger and they appear to hold the same value.* -- How would a debugger show "null characters"?  Unless you're looking at the raw memory, you can't show characters that are invisible.  Or maybe the debugger uses `c_str()` to display the values?

Comment: This 5-minute cppcon talk may be illuminating.  :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDJImePyftY

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I guess I thought it might show up as
a'\0''\0''\0'
but I guess you have a fair point.

Answer (score 6):

`test1` is the string `"a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`.  `test2` is the string `"a"`.  They are not equal.

`std::string` can contain null characters.  Its length is not the distance to the first null character.  It does also guarantee that the memory buffer containing the characters of the string ends with an additional null character 1 beyond its length.

If you don't intend for the string to be longer but just want the memory, use `std::string::reserve`.  Note that you cannot access elements beyond the end with `[]` legally, but pushing back or whatever won't cause any new memory allocations until you pass the reserve limit.

Answer (score 3):

This is the intended behavior of `std::string`.  Unlike a c-string a `std::string` can have as many null characters as you want.  For instance `"this\0 is\0 a\0 legal\0 std::string\0"` would be legal to have as the contents for a `std::string`.  You have to build it like

```
std::string nulls_inside("this\0 is\0 a\0 legal\0 std::string\0", sizeof("this\0 is\0 a\0 legal\0 std::string\0");
```

but you can also insert null characters into an existing `std::string`.  In your case you're comparing

```
"a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

against

```
"a\0"
```

so it fails.

Comment: thanks! I had no idea null characters could be in the middle of a string. I thought the first one would have made the other characters essentially dead.